# InvalidOperationException on EF

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using WPF MVVM Pettern and 
I Have a simple table on SQL Server 2012 which its `ID`(key) column is computed in an StoredProcedure, called `PersonInsert`: (This is simplified, but what is computed is more complex than this, anyway it's an `int` at last)

```
USE [Guard]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PersonInsert]
@FName NVARCHAR(50) ,
@LName NVARCHAR(50) ,
@ID INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT  @ID = ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1
        FROM    dbo.Person


        INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Person]
                ( [ID] ,
                  [FName] ,
                  [LName] 
                )
        VALUES  ( @ID ,
                  @FName ,
                  @LName 
                )
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
            @ErrSvr INT ,
            @ErrStt INT

        SELECT  @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE() + '|' + ERROR_PROCEDURE() + '|'
                + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR(5)) ,
                @ErrSvr = ERROR_SEVERITY() ,
                @ErrStt = ERROR_STATE()

        RAISERROR (@ErrMsg, @ErrSvr, @ErrStt)
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

In the .net side, I use **EF 6.1 Code-First** to handle data and mapped to SPs so I have `OnModelCreating` like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Person)().MapToStoredProcedures(
                    Sub(x)
                          x.Insert(Function(e) e.HasName("[dbo].[PersonInsert]"))
                          x.Update(Function(e) e.HasName("[dbo].[PersonUpdate]"))
                          x.Delete(Function(e) e.HasName("[dbo].[PersonDelete]"))
                    End Sub)
```

And My Model is:

```
<Table("Person")> _
Partial Public Class Person

    <DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None), Key> _
    Public Property ID As Integer

    Public Property FName As String
    Public Property LName as String
End Class
```

Now the strange thing is, when I try to Insert Data (Adding New Person) at first time, the `db.SaveChanged()` works great, but for second time it throws **InvalidOperation** exception with a message:

> The changes to the database were committed **successfully**, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'Shoniz.Guard.WPFGuardApplication.Person' have the **same primary key** value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or '**DatabaseGeneratedAttribute**' for Code First configuration.

He is right! the data is comitted successfully! and I'm right too, because my `ID`(key) column is computed right and it's completely unique. Either I have used the **DatabaseGeneratedAttribute** with **none** value on ID, but the result is the same :(

Even when I re-query the db to check about duplicate keys, I find NOTHING!

1. **Why this exception is thrown?**
2. **How can I prevent that?**
3. **Is there anyway to Ignore the changes after `db.SaveChanges()`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all change `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Indetity`
and finally change stored procedure to this:

```
BEGIN TRY
        SELECT  @ID = ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1
        FROM    dbo.Person


        INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Person]
                ( [ID] ,
                  [FName] ,
                  [LName] 
                )
        VALUES  ( @ID ,
                  @FName ,
                  @LName 
                )
        --You have to tell EF this is returned Id of inserted person
        SELECT @ID as ID
    END TRY
```

Comment: Really thanks Mohandes, I was confused how to tell EF this is my new generated ID.
I thought the Select @ID must return the New ID to Ef thus I tried to make my model Observable (Using INotifyPropertyChanged) but I didn't consider that __No Value is returned back from SQL  UNTIL I USE SELECT__.

Thank you again :)